# alignment buttons in PyQt4 of Python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

This is my first application using PyQt4.

I have the following two problems

[image]

1. the Buttons on left box. They have not the same spacing.
2. Is it possible use italics for the radio buttons? (i.e., Ke *et al.*
   instead of Ke et al.)?

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # title of the window
        self.setWindowTitle('Segmentation Accuracy')
        # fix window size
        self.setFixedSize(400,200)
        # status bar with initial message
        self.statusBar().showMessage('ready')


        # Layout
        # contiene gli altri widget
        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(cWidget) 


        # Box Left
        vBox_left = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vBox_left.setSpacing(2) #set spacing

        Button_input1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Reference Polygons")
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input1)

        Button_input2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Segmented Polygons")
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input2)

        Button_output = QtGui.QPushButton("Save")
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_output)

        Button_start = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        Button_start.setCheckable(True)

        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input1)
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input2)
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_output)
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_start)

        # Box right
        vBox_rigth = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vBox_rigth.setSpacing(10) #set spacing
        ke = QtGui.QRadioButton("Ke et al.", cWidget)
        pu = QtGui.QRadioButton("Pu et al.", cWidget)
        clinton = QtGui.QRadioButton("Clinton et al.", cWidget)
        ke.setChecked(True)
        vBox_rigth.addWidget(ke)
        vBox_rigth.addWidget(pu)
        vBox_rigth.addWidget(clinton)

        ke.setStatusTip("Ke et al., 2010. Remote Sensing of Environment, 114, pp. 1141-1154")
        pu.setStatusTip("Pu et al., 2012. Remote Sensing of Environment, 124, pp. 516-533")
        clinton.setStatusTip("Clinton et al., 2012. Remote Sensing of Environment, 124, pp. 516-533")

        grid.addWidget(Button_input1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(Button_input2, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(Button_output, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(Button_start, 3, 0)
        grid.addLayout(vBox_left, 0, 0)
        grid.addLayout(vBox_rigth, 0, 1)


        cWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `QGridLayout` and put `Button_input1` into cell (0,0) and the layout `vBox_rigth` containing three raido buttons into cell (0,1). They were resized to the same height. That's why your four buttons don't have the same spacing.

```
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(cWidget)
    ......
    grid.addWidget(Button_input1, 0, 0)
    ......
    grid.addLayout(vBox_rigth, 0, 1)
```

You should not use `addWidget` to add those buttons to `vBox_left` twice.

```
    Button_input1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Reference Polygons")
    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input1)

    Button_input2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Segmented Polygons")
    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input2)

    Button_output = QtGui.QPushButton("Save")
    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_output)

    Button_start = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
    Button_start.setCheckable(True)

    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input1)
    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input2)
    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_output)
    vBox_left.addWidget(Button_start)
```

Moreover, these four buttons have already been added to QVBoxLayout `vBox_left`, then you should not add them to `grid`.

```
    grid.addWidget(Button_input1, 0, 0)
    grid.addWidget(Button_input2, 1, 0)
    grid.addWidget(Button_output, 2, 0)
    grid.addWidget(Button_start, 3, 0)
```

You can use italics for widgets. You just need to change the `font` property. See http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qwidget.html#font-prop. 
For example:

```
    ke = QtGui.QRadioButton("Ke et al.", cWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont("Times", 10)
    font.setItalic(True)
    ke.setFont(font)
```

You can also use `QLabel` to display rich text. For instance:

```
    ke_label = QtGui.QLabel("Ke <i>et al</i>.")
```

Thus, the final `__init__` would probably be

```
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # title of the window
        self.setWindowTitle('Segmentation Accuracy')
        # fix window size
        self.setFixedSize(400,200)
        # status bar with initial message
        self.statusBar().showMessage('ready')


        # Layout
        # contiene gli altri widget
        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(cWidget)

        # Box Left
        vBox_left = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vBox_left.setSpacing(2) #set spacing

        Button_input1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Reference Polygons")
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input1)

        Button_input2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Segmented Polygons")
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input2)

        Button_output = QtGui.QPushButton("Save")
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_output)

        Button_start = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        Button_start.setCheckable(True)

        # vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input1)
        # vBox_left.addWidget(Button_input2)
        # vBox_left.addWidget(Button_output)
        vBox_left.addWidget(Button_start)

        # Box right
        vBox_right = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vBox_right.setSpacing(10) #set spacing

        ke = QtGui.QRadioButton("", cWidget)
        pu = QtGui.QRadioButton("", cWidget)
        clinton = QtGui.QRadioButton("", cWidget)
        ke.setChecked(True)

        ke_label = QtGui.QLabel("Ke <i>et al</i>.", cWidget)
        pu_label = QtGui.QLabel("Pu et al.", cWidget)
        clinton_label = QtGui.QLabel("Clinton et al.", cWidget)

        grid_right = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        grid_right.addWidget(ke, 0, 0)
        grid_right.addWidget(pu, 1, 0)
        grid_right.addWidget(clinton, 2, 0)
        grid_right.addWidget(ke_label, 0, 1)
        grid_right.addWidget(pu_label, 1, 1)
        grid_right.addWidget(clinton_label, 2, 1)
        grid.addLayout(grid_right, 0, 1)

        grid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        grid.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        grid_right.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

        ke.setStatusTip("Ke et al., 2010. Remote Sensing of Environment, 114, pp. 1141-1154")
        pu.setStatusTip("Pu et al., 2012. Remote Sensing of Environment, 124, pp. 516-533")
        clinton.setStatusTip("Clinton et al., 2012. Remote Sensing of Environment, 124, pp. 516-533")


        ke_label.setStatusTip("Ke et al., 2010. Remote Sensing of Environment, 114, pp. 1141-1154")
        pu_label.setStatusTip("Pu et al., 2012. Remote Sensing of Environment, 124, pp. 516-533")
        clinton_label.setStatusTip("Clinton et al., 2012. Remote Sensing of Environment, 124, pp. 516-533")

        # grid.addWidget(Button_input1, 0, 0)
        # grid.addWidget(Button_input2, 1, 0)
        # grid.addWidget(Button_output, 2, 0)
        # grid.addWidget(Button_start, 3, 0)
        grid.addLayout(vBox_left, 0, 0)
        #grid.addLayout(vBox_right, 0, 1)


        # cWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)
```

Comment: @Gianni, you can use `QLabel`. For example, `label = QtGui.QLabel("Ke<i> et al.</i>")`.

Comment: sorry nymk, I didn't understand where insert label = QtGui.QLabel("Ke<i> et al.</i>") in my code

Comment: @Gianni, you can replace the radio button by a `QHBoxLayout` containing a `QRadioButton` with blank text and a `QLabel`, or use a `QGridLayout` to contain the radio buttons and labels. I updated my post. I used `QGridLayout`.